# How to tell the difference of meaning of "anxiety"

Tags: word-usage

I found out that the word, "anxiety" has two different meaning.

 One is feeling of worry. Another is eagerness. 

 I think the two meanings of "anxiety" are completely different

 If someone says, he has anxiety and so on, how can I tell the difference?

Comment: Using "anxiety" to mean "eagerness" or "keenness" is almost entirely limited to the word "anxious", as in "I was anxious to get things done". A person "*having* anxiety" is worried - it is not implied that they are eager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, context will supply the meaning. 'Anxious' used in the sense of 'eager' or 'desirous' will often be followed by 'to', whereas the 'worry' meaning may be followed by 'about': my father is anxious to know when his car will be repaired, I am anxious about my forthcoming college examination. Although many style or grammar guides frown upon the 'eager' usage, Fowler does not discourage it. The sense has been seen as long ago as 1570. Writers who have used it thus include Jane Austen, Kingsley Amis, Lord Byron, and Flannery O’Connor.

[Can 'anxious' be used to mean 'eager'? (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/can-anxious-be-used-to-mean-eager)

Comment: How common is 'frown' with the transitive sense 'to show displeasure with or disapproval of especially by facial expression' {[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frown)} nowadays?

Comment: Extremely uncommon, I would have thought; my use was accidental.

Comment: While I'm in a nit-picking mood (I know it's highly unusual), how up-to-date would you say Fowler is in 2019? I'd say some of the stuff it contains is still highly pertinent and valuable, but one has to be selective.

Comment: I agree one must be selective. rather than the 1926 edition, I have the Burchfield 3rd Edition (revised) of 1998, which says "in the 18c, the adjective [anxious] began to turn on its axis and came also to mean 'full of desire and endeavour; earnestly desirous (to bring about some purpose)'. The latest supporting quote is a 1982 one (AN Wilson).

Comment: I was delighted to see John Lawler essentially label CGEL as dated now.